# I am writing a single login app using react and django but i cant send anything from the front end to the backend. it gives me 403 error

Tags: reactjs, django

i want to know how to send the csrf token. i searched but i coudn't know how.
here is my code

I want to send the username and the password to the backend from here

```
const LoginPage = () => {

const [username , setUsername] = useState('')
const [password , setPassword] = useState('')

const handlelogin = async () => {
    function getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

await fetch('http://localhost:8000/auth/login' ,    
                    {
                        method : "POST" ,
                        headers : {
                            "X-CSRFToken" : csrftoken
                        }, 
                        body : {
                           " username" : username , 
                            "password" : password
                        }
                    }
             ).then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
 }

return (
\<div\>
\<div className=" mx-auto"\>
<h1 className=" font-bold sm:text-2xl md:text-3xl p-6 font-serif"> Tailwindcss Login Card</h1>

            <div className="card" >
            <label className=" font-bold">Username:</label>
                <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Enter username" 
                className="inputs"
                onChange={(e)=>{ setUsername(e.target.value)}}
                 />
                <label className=" font-bold">Password:</label>
                <input 
                type="password" 
                placeholder="Enter password" 
                className="inputs"
                onChange={(e) => {setPassword(e.target.value)}}
                />
                    <button className="buttons" onClick={handlelogin}>Login</button>
                    <p className=' text-center'>
                    Sign up if you don't have an account
                    </p>
                    <button className="buttons bg-blue-600 active:bg-blue-800">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
           
            <div className=" mt-5 text-right hover:scale-105 hover:text-blue-700">
                <a  href="/" >Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

export default LoginPage

and here is my backend code:

is this the correct way to take the username and the password from the response and am i doing it right?

```
def login(request):
username = request.body.username
password = request.body.password
user = authenticate(request , username = username , password = password)
if user is not None:
login(request , user)
return JsonResponse({'response':'you have successfully put reached here'})
else:
return JsonResponse('you are not allowed here')
```

i am expecting the fetch to send it to the backend and then send back the response

Comment: please add your django api code properly with indentation

Answer (score -1):

I found that because i am using cross domain i cannot obtain the csrftoken using ajax.
And i the react-cookie package didn't work for me.
I read this article and in it the solution was that you send a request to the backend to get the csrf token and then use it in the front-end when you want to send a form.

you also have to add these lines in the settings.py to allow the connection for cors and the third line of code is for the csrf trusted origins because it is not from the same domain:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['http://localhost:3000']
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:3000']
```

after this step you designate a view to get the csrf token like and django has a function that creates that token which you have to import get_token(request)

```
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token

def gettoken(request):
return JsonResponse({'csrftoken': get_token(request)})
```

last step is that from the frontend you then make an api call to this function whenever you are sending a form to the backend.

here is the part of the code from the front end after i deleted the ajax.

```
await fetch('http://localhost:8000/auth/gettoken')                      
             .then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
 }
```